# Should the three dialect tags be synonyms? Should they be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should the three dialect tags be synonyms? Should they be merged? I think so. I would like to hear your opinion.

[dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialect)

[dialect2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialect2)

[dialects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialects)

Comment: sounds like a terrible tag. If a person means SQL Dialect, there should be a tag `sql-dialect`. Similarly for Hibernate, NHibernate and what not.

Comment: @KateGregory: Thanks for your comment. Let's wait to see what the moderators say.

Comment: Are there any news about this?